# Wrapper hight does not update after adding element with javascript

Tags: html, css

I want to add an input element, type text to my form but by doing that my form overlaps the footer of my page. I tried adding an overflow attribute but that didn't work. I'm pretty new to web development and I can't figure out a solution.

This is my CSS:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 99%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -100px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 110px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
    height: 110px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
*
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
            <div class="text-xs-center">
                <form id="questionForm" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                    <label>Question</label></br>
                    <textarea name="Question" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea></br>
                    <label>Answers:</label></br>
                    <input id="1" name="Answer1" type="text"/></br></br>
                    <input id="2" name="Answer2" type="text"/></br></br>
                    <button id="addAnswerButton" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="addAnswerField()">Add Answer Field</button></br></br>
                    <noscript>
                        <p>Please enable Java-Script to add more answers</p>
                    </noscript>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function addAnswerField(){
                            var form = document.getElementById("questionForm");
                            var thisButton = document.getElementById("addAnswerButton");

                            // find last Index
                            var lastIndex = 1;
                            var lastElement = document.getElementById(lastIndex.toString());
                            while (lastElement != null) {
                                lastIndex++;
                                console.log(lastIndex.toString());
                                lastElement = document.getElementById(lastIndex.toString());
                            }

                            var input = document.createElement("input");
                            input.type = "text";
                            input.name = "Answer" + lastIndex;
                            input.id = lastIndex.toString();

                            form.insertBefore(input, thisButton);
                            form.insertBefore(document.createElement("br"), thisButton);
                            form.insertBefore(document.createElement("br"), thisButton);
                        }
                    </script>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success"/>
                </form>
            </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- Content -->

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container small">
        <p class="text-muted small">I don't have any rights on the Harry Potter Universe. All rights belong to their rightful owners.
            This site is using cookies to identify you for the next month. <br/>
            Credits - Idea: Laura Weasley Kletschko - Implementation: Niko Percival Wulfric Brian Tzioras <br/>
            <a href="impressum.html">Impressumg & Datenschutz</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</footer>

</body>
```

Comment: Show html also.

Comment: @atulquest93 here you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add one element above footer like.

```
<div class="push">

</div>
<footer class="footer">
```

Comment: Could you explain why this works perfectly for me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[Find solution here][1]
 or just remove negative value of wrapper's margin

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/437jtp3j/1
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi check this https://plnkr.co/edit/4PuGswOMqpuKMDktkVqA

```
html, body {
height: 99%;
}

.wrapper {
height: 82%;
overflow:auto;
}
.footer {
width: 100%;
height: 18%;
overflow:hidden;
}
```